# Custom Filter for ng-repeat in controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I create a controller that shows data in `li` using `ng-repeat`.

The data has a variable called `filter` and used for categorizing the data. Now I want to filter the `li` based on this variable and want to do it by using buttons.

But I don't know how to connect the filter to the data in the controller.
I create plunkr for it: [plunkr](https://embed.plnkr.co/w6bqrV/)

Comment: theres no ng-repeat in your plunkr buddy. this is AngularJS file reader example

Comment: @Bowofola Hi, I edit the link.

Comment: Did my answer work ?

Answer (score 0):

- there is an in-built filter named 'filter' and it works perfectly for this
- updated `filter` to be an object `currentFilter`, and defaulted `currentFilter.filter` to "app" which tells filter which property on the objects to filter on.
- added the buttons and a tied them to a function on the scope that sets `currentFilter.filter` when they are clicked
- updated ng-repeat to use the 'currentFilter' and set strict to true so it matches the word exactly. By default strict is false and works like a predicate.

angular docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter#example

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app
  .controller('isotopeCtrl', isotopeFunction);

function isotopeFunction($scope) {
    $scope.names = ['website-1', 'website-2', 'app-1', 'psd-1', 'psd-2', 'psd-3'];
    $scope.currentFilter = {
      filter: 'app'
    };
    $scope.data = [{
            name: 'website-1',
            filter: 'website'
        },
        {
            name: 'website-2',
            filter: 'website'
        },
        {
            name: 'app-1',
            filter: 'app'
        }
    ];
    $scope.setFilter = function(filter) {
        $scope.currentFilter.filter = filter;
    };
    console.log($scope.names);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.5.11"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="isotopeCtrl">
    <h2>Simple Data</h2>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in data">
            <div>{{ item.name }}</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <h2>Using Filter</h2>
    
    <p>Here I used a dynamic filter - {{ currentFilter.filter }} )</p>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in data | filter:currentFilter:true">
            <div>{{ item.name }}</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    Filters
    <button ng-click="setFilter('app')">app</button>
    <button ng-click="setFilter('website')">website</button>
  </body>

</html>
```